# Implementing the Commands of CQRS in a Web environment with dependency INjection

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, dependency-injection, command-pattern

I'm currently experimenting with some architectural patterns, one of them being the implementation of [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html), especially the "Command" part of the pattern.

Basically I have commands like

```
public class SavePersonCommand {

   @Inject
   private IPersonRepository repository;

   Person person;

   public SavePersonCommand(Person personToSave){
      this.person = personToSave;
   }

   public void execute(){
      ...
      repository.save(personToSave);
      ...
   }
}
```

For simplicity I don't specify any interfaces/abstract classes the command might implement. The point is, this is the standard implementation of a Command, you pass all the necessary information to the constructor and then you have a parameterless method (i.e. `execute()`) which executes the business logic of your command.

The issue though is `IPersonRepository`. `IPersonRepository` contains the logic for persisting the entity to some storage and thus belongs to the **data layer** of my application. Btw, the simplified structure of my app is like this

```
ApiLayer -> Core <- DAL
```

where ApiLayer depend on Core and DAL depends on Core. Meaning Core does not have dependencies on the specific DAL nor does it obviously have on the Api layer. So the distribution of the classes would be..

```
ApiLayer
  PersonApi
Core
  IPersonRepository
  PersonCommand
  Person
DAL
  PersonRepository -> IPersonRepository
```

Now, in the ApiLayer, where I want would normally get an instance of the `SavePersonCommand`.

```
@Path("/api/v1/person")
public class PersonApi {

   @POST
   public void savePerson(Person person) {
      SavePersonCommand personCommand = new SavePersonCommand(person);
      personCommand.execute();
   }

}
```

The **issue here is however, how do I get the `IPersonRepository`** injected into the command. I wouldn't want to get it injected in the `ApiLayer` like

```
@Path("/api/v1/person")
public class PersonApi {

   @Inject
   private IPersonRespository personRepo;

   @POST
   public void savePerson(Person person) {
      // obviously modify the interface of SavePersonCommand
      SavePersonCommand personCommand = new SavePersonCommand(personRepo, person);
      ...
   }
}
```

..this is kinda ugly..

I have some thoughts but would like to hear how you implement this normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Steven's hints the simplest approach to solve my issue is the following.

### Core Layer

Here I have the following

```
public class SavePersonCommandHandler implements ICommandHandler<SavePersonCommand> {

    @Inject
    IPersonRepository personRepository;

    @Override
    public void handle(SavePersonCommand command) {
        Person person = command.getPerson();
        personRepository.save(person); 
    }
}
```

The `SavePersonCommand` is simply a data object that transfers the data from my Api layer to the Core layer.

```
public class SavePersonCommand {
    private Person person;

    public SavePersonCommand(Person person) {
       this.person = person;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
       return this.person;
    }
}
```

I could even only pass the person's properties as native data types rather than passing the entire `Person` object. Thus, I could remove the dependency to the datatype which I might want to only use in my core layer.

### Api Layer

The api layer then gets an instance of the required command handler.

```
@Path("/api/v1/person")
public class PersonApi {

   @Inject
   ICommandHandler<SavePersonCommand> commandHandler;

   @POST
   public void savePerson(Person person) {
      commandHandler.handle(new SavePersonCommand(person));
   }

}
```

**Note** that normally you also add a Bus in between that "sends" a command down the pipe which then gets intercepted by the correct CommandHandler. Didn't want to complicate as for the sake of my question this is the answer I found.

These articles were quite helpful:

- https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91 (provided by Steven's answer, so he deserves an upvote ;) )
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/555855/Introduction-to-CQRS
- https://github.com/erikrozendaal/cqrs-lottery

Answer (score 3):

The problems you are experiencing is because you are applying the [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). The command pattern is very useful when it comes to creating user interfaces, but not so much when it comes to abstracting away business logic.

Because your command contains both data and behavior, it becomes much harder to:

1. Test the consumer of that command in isolation.
2. Inject dependencies into the command, since the consumer should create the command, but should not be aware of the any dependency injection mechanism.

As a matter of fact, the commands that the CQRS pattern describes is something different than what the Command Pattern describes. Commands in CQRS are merely messages; they don't contain any behavior.

So what you must do is extract the behavior from the command into its own class: the command handler. Take a look at [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) which describes this pattern in more depth. The article is written in the context of .NET, but I think it is applicable to Java as well.

Comment: Yea, I see, in fact that's what I'm currently fighting with...Just found this article which seems quite good: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/555855/Introduction-to-CQRS

So basically my `SavePersonCommmand` should just be used to transport data, while I need some `SavePersonCommandHandler` that contains the actual business logic...I see

Comment: @Juri: Exactly. And if you use the same generic interface for all command handlers, you can easily apply cross-cutting concerns over them.

Comment: In fact, now I got it....read about such approach before, but couldn't recall it. Thx!